# Rails accepts_nested_attributes_for validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

An `Image has_many :categories`.
It also a`ccepts_nested_attributes_for :categories`.
`Categories` only have an `id` and a `description`. Rather than create repeat categories with the same description, I want it to validate the category `before_create` so that if the `category` the user enters already exists, it will just set the `category` to the `category` that already exists.

I have tried adding hooks to both the `Image class` and the `Category class`, but neither way seems to be changing the `Category` so that it passes validation.

Here is what I have tried (adding this both on the `Image class` and the `Category class`):

```
class Image

before_create :validate_description

  def validate_description
    puts "I RAN AND VALIDATED!"

    categories.each do |cat|
      // since an image can have multiple categories it is iterating through it
      cat.id = Category.find_or_create_by(description: cat.description) || nil
      cat.description = nil
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are hooks that can be used on the association, a la:

```
has_many :categories, after_add: :chk_category
```

which will cause the chk_category method to be called each time a category is added to the Image, so, you could then do something like:

```
def chk_user(category)
  exist_category = Category.where(title: category.title).first
  if exist_category
    self.categories = self.categories + [exist_category]
    self.categories = self.categories - [category]
  end
end
```

You will want to write some tests here to be sure your are avoiding recursion, etc, but I think the hooks should help.

Comment: Thank you! That works but I'm wondering if there is a way that I can add a `validation` directly to the `Category class` via a `hook` that will allow it to refer to itself or create a new instance if it already exists. It is the `Category class`'s responsibility to validate itself, not the `Image class`.

Comment: If you have validation set up on the Category class, it will be honored in this solution. So just use normal validation in the Category class. I.E. if you are using this, and the category(s) passed in via `code`(Image.categories_attributes) represents a new category, it will be created, and will be validated in the process.

Comment: There are also the `before_create` and other hooks that could be added to Category as well. These might be made to work for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the best solution but it should get you started.

```
# Get the value of the category_description from the form
@category_description = params[:image][:category_attributes][:description]

# check if it already exists
if Category.exists?(description: @category_description)
  # if it exists then find the category and pass it to the image
  @existing_category = Category.where(description: @category_description).first

  @image = Image.new(image_params.merge({ category: @existing_category }))
else
  # if not, create a new image and category
  @image = Image.new(image_params)
end
```

There are a few ways to find an existing category, but this should get you going!